# Get document information where ajax is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This might not be a well formulated question, what I need is the metadata from the document where the script is begin executed not from where the data is extracted...
We have foo.com/some_title_article.html
inside of it, we have an script

```
<script>
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = data.qids;
    var theTime = new Date().getTime();
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://foo.com/apis/shares/api.php?ids="+id+"&amp;time="+theTime
    }).done(function(data) {
      $('#showData').html(data); // This will show a basic html form...
    });
});
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

inside the file api.php I call a few other java scripts that are related to where that file is stored, as it is right now is working fine, but what I need is to get metadata from some_title_article.html into my other java scripts that is loaded via ajax... sortof like `var currentURL = window.location.href;` which is declared inside and a java script inside the api.php file, it load the full url as **foo.com/some_title_article.html** and not **foo.com/apis/shares/api.php** ...get it?., So, how can get information from the url where the ajax is executed and pass it to the other scripts that are called after the ajax script...

Comment: you are using java with php, why?

Comment: I think it's a typo: javascript not java script...

Comment: if your variables are global then your javascript present in the data varable once appended should see them

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<div id="showData"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://foo.com/apis/shares/api.php?ids="+id+"&amp;time="+theTime
    }).done(function(data) {
      var content = data.content;
      var metadata = data.metadata;
      $('#showData').html(content); // This will show a basic html form...
      //Then, do whatever you want to with metadata
    });
</script>
```

You make api.php return an object where the first key is the content and the second key is the meta data.

Otherwise, if api.php returns a string that already contains meta tags in it, you would need to parse them or add them to the dom and access them that way.

Can you share a sample of what is returned by api.php?